# Get subset Data from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview, dataset

I have the following valid JSON data (tested from http://jsonlint.com/):

```
{
  "alpha": {
    "one": 1,
    "two": "2"
  },
  "bravo": {
    "sample1": {
      "one": "1",
      "two": "2",
      "three": 3
    },
    "sample2": [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "content": "alpha",
        "photos": [
          {
            "caption": "photo1",
            "location": [
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/abc.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              },
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/def.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "caption": "photo2",
            "location": [
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/ghi.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              },
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/jkl.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 456,
        "content": "bravo",
        "photos": [
          {
            "caption": "photo3",
            "location": [
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/mno.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              },
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/pqr.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "caption": "photo4",
            "location": [
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/stu.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              },
              {
                "url": "http://website.com/vwx.jpg",
                "width": 800,
                "height": 600
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to pass the JSON data to a DataSet so I can display it from GridView control.

Is there a way to only display values found inside "sample2" where I can display the following:

```
id     content     caption     url
123    alpha       photo1      http://website.com/abc.jpg
456    bravo       photo3      http://website.com/mno.jpg
```

I'm using JSON.NET's [JsonConvert](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) to pass the value from a DataSet to the GridView control

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>("JSON file here");
GridView.DataBind();
```

but receiving an error:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got
>   StartObject. Path 'alpha'...

Am I missing something? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you need a valid `class` for your JSON to parse too. Something like this (Thanks to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)):

```
public class Alpha
{
    public int one { get; set; }
    public string two { get; set; }
}

public class Sample1
{
    public string one { get; set; }
    public string two { get; set; }
    public int three { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public List<Location> location { get; set; }
}

public class Sample2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
}

public class Bravo
{
    public Sample1 sample1 { get; set; }
    public List<Sample2> sample2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Alpha alpha { get; set; }
    public Bravo bravo { get; set; }
}
```

**Next** your `JSON.net` call is wrong, it should look like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("JSON String here"); // not the file!
// Insert here some magic to convert your RootObject to DataSet
```

**Also** your question:

> Is there a way to only display values found inside "sample2" where I can display the following

Is a simple **NO**. You have to restructure your JSON Model or parse the `RootObject` to a suitable ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create classes for the data that you don't need, you can access the part that you need directly:

```
JObject jsonTree = JObject.Parse(json);
var sample2 = jsonTree["bravo"]["sample2"].ToString();

List<Sample2> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample2>(sample2);
```

Classes needed:

```
public class Photo
{
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public List<Location> location { get; set; }
}

public class Sample2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can easily bind `data` to your gird.

Comment: @BWA It is a local variable name holding the json Document, updated.